# Cannot enable 'Install from web' and cannot upload extension manually

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, file-upload

I have just setup a joomla 3 site on `demojoomla.com`. I have managed to upload a template but I have not been able to upload any extensions (JCE or Akeeba).

When I try to enable Install fromm web I get an error

> Can't connect to the Joomla! server. Please try again later.

If I try to upload the extension then either there is no response (just hangs) or there is a fairly quick Request timeout.

Does demojoomla.com not allow extensions (haven't found any info) ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an ssl/https problem. Simply changed https to http in the url and then I was able to enable the Install from web feature.